# How to connect two routers each connected to internet on one home network and provide failover

Tags: home-networking

I have the following setup at home:

1. Switch
2. Wireless ADSL 3Com router connected to internet through ISP and connected to a switch
3. Another wireless 3G router connected to the switch as well

The reason i am having 2 routers is to simply to extend the WiFi coverage.

The configuration is as follows:

1. 3Com
   IP 192.168.1.1
   gateweay 192.168.1.1
   DHCP enabled 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.200
2. 3G router
   IP 192.168.1.2
   gateweay 192.168.1.1
   DHCP disabled

This setup is working extremely fine and i can connect from anywhere at home either wired or wireless to the internet.

My question is : Since i have 3G internet connection on the 3G router and i am currently making no use of it. Is there a setup to have 3G internet as automatic backup for the main internet connection, without having to change the gateway address on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the pair of routers to extend wifi coverage I presume they are not close to each other, which complicates things. My ideal solution would be to use a Draytek 2800G wireless-enabled ADSL router (second hand on Ebay approx 50UKP and sell your other kit) or a (new) Draytek 2820n (a bit pricey) as they directly support a 3G stick (check the compatibility list) for failover. If you need to extend wifi coverage you could do this with a wired or powerline link to a basic Access Point.

Using the current kit will require some form of intermediate load balancer or failover detection system, which could be PC-based but if you are going down the route of extra kit this may cost you anyway unless you have a spare PC to hand - and you're going to end up with 3 bits of equipment all consuming electricity, which will probably cost you more in the long run.